# css hover on a link - not working

Tags: html, css, hover

[This is the site](http://54.169.61.153/responsibility/coffeehouse/merchandise/mobile-apps/starbucks-mobile-applications)

The last section has a button - Join Now.

At the moment the button on hover has - green background and white text. I wanted it to be white background and green text.

I tried this code :

```
 .joen_now_part h6 a:hover {
   background-color: #fff;
   color: #2a8a15;

 }
```

But for some reasons nothing changes.

Help and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is already some class applied   so have to overwrite the class

this is the default class its applying

```
a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
    background-color: #2a8a15;
    color: #fff;
}
```

so u have to add this

```
 .joen_now_part h6 a:hover {
   background-color: #fff !important;
   color: #2a8a15 !important;

 }
```

for [reference](https://plnkr.co/edit/qpoPOV5MYruWk9h6QfRT?p=preview)

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried that but still nothing changes.

Comment: from he link i check your class not applied

Comment: Because that's live - and I tried on my staging server. I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: check my above link from the answer or https://plnkr.co/edit/qpoPOV5MYruWk9h6QfRT?p=preview

Comment: For some reasons - it only shows when I'm on mobile sizes. Why?

Comment: may be becz of media quries please apply the above changes on stage then tel me will check for mobile size

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this [codepen](http://codepen.io/bubblesphere/pen/WxXAoj)

```
.yourButton {
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #2a8a15;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-transform: Uppercase;
  color: #2a8a15;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.yourButton:hover, yourButton:focus, yourButton:active {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #2a8a15;
}
```